# "Orthotopic" or "orthotopal"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, suffixes, greek, derivational-morphology

An *n-orthotope* is a fancy name for an n-dimensional cube. I'd like to describe an object that has this quality. Which is the correct adjective: *orthotopic* or *orthotopal*?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47171/term-for-tetrahedron-with-three-right-angles-at-a-point/47201#47201

Comment: That was my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a similar word *polytope* used in mathematics, and it seems you should use the same adjectival form for *polytope* and *orthotope*. Looking at the arXiv, if we use Google to search the arXiv for the word *polytopal,* we get [715 hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aarxiv.org+polytopal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=i9e&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=site%3aarxiv.org+polytopal&pbx=1&oq=site%3aarxiv.org+polytopal&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=56907l58330l1l58604l10l8l0l0l0l0l214l1160l0.7.1l8l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=34122e398b5a64cb&biw=909&bih=427), whereas the word *polytopic* only gives [119 hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aarxiv.org+polytopal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=Zqz&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&source=hp&q=site%3Aarxiv.org%20polytopic&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=34122e398b5a64cb&biw=909&bih=427&pf=p&pdl=300). Looking at a few examples gives me the general sense that in mathematics, *polytopal* and *polytopic* are synonyms. So I'd suggest using *orthotopal*.

Note that Google Ngrams suggests that *polytopic* is more widely used than *polytopal* among the general public, but it seems to me that you would be more interested in what a mathematical audience uses. Many of the uses of *polytopic* appear to be in biochemistry. Also note that *isotopic* is a word, but *isotopal* does not seem to be one.